# DropdownList from webservice reset after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

My list is populated from a webservice call.

If i populate the list manually line by line its ok. I can select the item and return the selectem item with no problem e.g.

```
List<ListItem> oList = new List<ListItem>();

oList.Add(new ListItem("User", "0"));
oList.Add(new ListItem("Manager", "1"));

cboUsers.DataSource = oList
```

Thats not practical as the list I want to bind to is Dynamic, e.g.

```
cboUsers.DataSource = MyWebService.GetUsers() // returns List<ListItem>
```

No matter what I do in code I cannot get the the selected item from the list and the list ALWAYS resets itself.

Both items of code are enclosed within

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

But when the list is bound to a web service no matter what I do (ViewState, Session anything) the list is ALWAYS reset after postback and I can NEVER get the selected item correctly.

I have tried every combination of properties on pages, controls in code and in the mark up and nothing works. I have looked at loads of articles on here and other websites and none of their examples work.

Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT]

The full code is below.
(cboAccess, manually filled work just fine as expected)
(cboDept will fill and display but after that I can get no selection from it)

You make a selection from the dropdown (cboDept) then click the Add button (cmdAdd) which adds the text selection from the list to my database using my web service. The selection is ALWAYS shown to be the first item no matter what I select.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AttendanceWebServices.Service1Client oServices = new AttendanceWebServices.Service1Client();

            List<ListItem> oList = new List<ListItem>();
            oList.Add(new ListItem("Normal User", "0"));
            oList.Add(new ListItem("Manager", "10"));

            cboAccess.DataTextField = "Text";
            cboAccess.DataValueField = "Value";
            cboAccess.DataSource = oList;
            cboAccess.DataBind();

            cboDept.DataSource = oServices.GetTeamGroups().ToList();
            cboDept.DataValueField = "Value";
            cboDept.DataTextField = "Text";
            cboDept.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AttendanceWebServices.Service1Client oServices = new AttendanceWebServices.Service1Client();

        string sDept = ((ListItem)cboDept.SelectedItem).Text;

        oServices.AddNewUser(sDept);
    }
}
```

[EDIT2 - HTML]

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="adduser.ascx.cs" Inherits="AttendanceWeb2.adduser" %>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>

<asp:scriptmanager runat="server" id="scm1">
</asp:scriptmanager>

<table class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Department</td>
        <td>
            <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboDept" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdAdd" />
                </triggers>
            </asp:updatepanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Employee ID</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Access Level</td>
        <td>
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="cboAccess"></asp:dropdownlist>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" onclick="cmdAdd_Click" Text="Add" 
                Width="100px" />
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" onclick="cmdDelete_Click" Text="Delete" 
                Width="100px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[EDIT 3] - Simplified Version (Still does not work)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AttendanceWeb2._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboDept" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" Width="100px" 
            onclick="cmdAdd_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AttendanceWebServices.Service1Client oServices = new AttendanceWebServices.Service1Client();

            cboDept.DataSource = oServices.GetTeamGroups().ToList();
            cboDept.DataValueField = "Value";
            cboDept.DataTextField = "Text";
            cboDept.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem oItem = cboDept.SelectedItem;

        string sText = oItem.Text;
        string sValue = oItem.Value;
    }
```

Comment: I  have a single dropdown. It makes no difference whether I use selected index or not

Comment: Do you could show your asp control?

Comment: I have updated the question to show my full code

Comment: Show your view code...

Comment: @Wilfredo P: Above code will work if the control has view state enabled...

Comment: @st4hoo I forget that :P

Comment: EnableViewState="false" clears my list. EnableViewState="true" has no effect

Comment: Also using an UpdatePanel does nothing

Comment: Store it somewhere like a session variable and bind

Comment: that still does not work. there is no scenario where I can get the correctly selected item

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `EnableViewState` set to `True` for your `cboDept` control.

**EDIT**

Put your table inside a `form`. Example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button type="submit" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Changing the EnableViewState property either does nothing or clears the list on postback.

Comment: Make sure that you run right version(with view state enabled) - clean cache, etc...

Comment: What value do you have under `cboDept.SelectedItem` When `EnableViewState` is set to `True` for `cboDept` ? Check in debugger...

Comment: EnableViewState="true" SelectedItem is ALWAYS first item. EnableViewState="false then SelectedItem ALWAYS null

Comment: HTML is included above

Comment: Place everything in some `form` ... and remove that update panel - it is not needed...

Comment: I have tried a form and a user control in a form. Neither of which makes any difference

Comment: Have added a simplified version and still the same problem. See [EDIT-3] above